# NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 on insertBefore in event listener

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="tree">
  <ul class="root">
    <li class="add">+</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = () => {
  let root = document.getElementsByClassName("root")[0];
  root.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("add")) addNode(e);
    return false;
  }, false);

  function addNode(e) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = "new";
    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(e.target, item);
  }
};
```

When I click the li I get the Error `NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.` on the line with insertBefore. I've checked with the DevTools and everything seems to be a normal node, I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the arguments is incorrect. The new node has to be passed first:

```
e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(item, e.target);
```

[See the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Comment: Thanks, once again my own stupidity got me. I just realised it too and was about to post my own answer.